# Why it's not possible to save the older HTMLElement object inside an object?

Tags: javascript

I've got the following simplified code to a problem I was facing yesterday when I've asked this question:

[Problem of JavaScript previous object inside an object is being overwritten [EDITED]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63583747/problem-of-javascript-previous-object-inside-an-object-is-being-overwritten-edi?noredirect=1#comment112436502_63583747)

The simplified code is:
**HTML**

```
<div class="header"><button>click me to add new to DOM and Object</button></div>
    <div class="list"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
const list = document.querySelector(".list");
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const obj = {
  counter: 1
}

function html(counter) {
  return `<div>I am Item number ${obj.counter}</div>`;
}
function addItem() {
  //add new element to the DOM
  list.innerHTML += html(obj.counter);
  //add new object to the object
  obj[`ITEM-${obj.counter++}`] = [...list.querySelectorAll("div")].slice(-1)[0];
  console.log(obj);
}
button.addEventListener("click", addItem);
```

The problem is:
I'm console.logging the "obj" to see it's content,
I want you to look at the console after some clicks on the button, you'll see this output

```
{counter: 6, ITEM-1: div, ITEM-2: div, ITEM-3: div, ITEM-4: div, …}
ITEM-1: div
ITEM-2: div
ITEM-3: div
ITEM-4: div
ITEM-5: div
counter: 6
__proto__: Object
```

The question is:
Why only the last item from inside the object is indicating the HTML code from inside the dom while the other previous items are no longer indicating the HTML elements?

to try what I'm trying to say:
please, inside the console, hover on the last item from the object, in my case, it's `ITEM-5: div`,
you'll see how the item on the DOM is being highlighted.

but now try to hover on previous items from inside the object, for example in my case

```
ITEM-1: div
```

it's not being highlighted on the DOM.

what is the problem?

Comment: beause innerHTML replaces the elements

Comment: Why? I'm using += to append items rather than overwriting them

Comment: It recreates the DOM when you do it....

Comment: never use `+=` on `.innerHTML`.   It requires that the existing content of the element be serialised into HTML, and then you add your content to that string, and then the entire thing has to be deserlalised back onto DOM, forcing the existing nodes to be recreated.

Comment: Thanks this is the answer I was looking for

Comment: look into using `insertAdjacentHTML` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never use += on `.innerHTML`.

It is precisely equivalent to:

```
element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML + content
```

In other words it requires that the existing content of the element be serialised into HTML, and then you add your content to that string, and then the entire thing is re-assigned to the node (which has to be de-serialised back onto DOM format again), also forcing the previously-existing child nodes to be recreated.

Comment: thanks for this detailed comment, could you please add a link to an online tutorial or from the MDN to explain this concept more?

Answer (score 2):

When you are using innerHTML to add an element you are basically erasing all the elements and creating new ones. So when you create a reference to the element, the element is removed when the innerHTML is replaced.

Typically your question is asked as "Why do my click event handlers only work on the last element when I add to the list?"

Looking at the code you are doing

```
var current = list.innerHTML; // string of existing HTML
var newString = html(obj.counter); // String of new HTML
var updated = current + newString; // Combine to make a new string
list.innerHTML = updated; // redraw the DOM with the new string
```

When you change the innerHTML directly, it does not figure out what changes in the string, it just clears the "whiteboard" and redraws it all. If you do not what to redraw the whole element, you need to get smarter and instruct it to what is being added.

You should be appending a new element, not building it as a string.

```js
const list = document.querySelector(".list");
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const obj = {
  counter: 1
}

function elem(counter) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = `I am Item number ${obj.counter}`;
  return div
}

function addItem() {
  var newDiv = elem(obj.counter)
  list.appendChild(newDiv);
  obj[`ITEM-${obj.counter++}`] = newDiv;
  console.log(obj);
}
button.addEventListener("click", addItem);
```

```html
<div class="header"><button>click me to add new to DOM and Object</button></div>
<div class="list"></div>
```